# selecting marker on geochart

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-visualization

I have a few cities plotted on a Geochart and I'm trying to simply allow the user to click on a marker to select their location. For now, I'm just using an alert box for testing.

Right now I'm ONLY listing city names, no population, size, area, or numbers are attached.

**edit-this runs in jsFiddle, however I can't get it to run on it's own page. Does anyone see something that I don't?**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">

google.load('visualization', '1', {
'packages': ['geochart']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMarkersMap);

function drawMarkersMap() {

   var newInfo = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['City'],
     ['Rome'],
     ['Truth or Consequences'],
     ['Ann Arbor'],
     ['Chico'],
     ['Los Angeles'],
     ['Seattle'],
     ['Chicago'],
     ['Lubbock']
     ]);

var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('geoChart'));

chart.draw(newInfo, {
    width: 667,
    height: 416,
    datalessRegionColor: '#3FADD1',
    tooltip: {
        textStyle: {
            color: 'blue'
        },
        showColorCode: false
    },
    displayMode: 'markers',
    region: 'US',
    resolution: 'provinces'
   });

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function() {
    var selection = chart.getSelection();

    // if same city is clicked twice in a row
    // it is "unselected", and selection = []
    if(typeof selection[0] !== "undefined") {
      var value = newInfo.getValue(selection[0].row, 0);
      alert('City is: ' + value);
    }
});

};​
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="geoChart" style="width: 250px; height: 400px;"></div>
</body>​
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure I understood exactly what you want, though I got the following demo to display cities and be clickable. The response is the alert box with the city name.

http://jsfiddle.net/Mep7R/4/

Here's the relevant code:

```
function drawMarkersMap() {

var newInfo = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['City'],
    ['Rome'],
    ['Truth or Consequences'],
    ['Ann Arbor'],
    ['Chico'],
    ['Los Angeles'],
    ['Seattle'],
    ['Chicago'],
    ['Lubbock']
    ]);

var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('geoChart'));

chart.draw(newInfo, {
    width: 667,
    height: 416,
    datalessRegionColor: '#3FADD1',
    tooltip: {
        textStyle: {
            color: 'blue'
        },
        showColorCode: false
    },
    displayMode: 'markers',
    region: 'US',
    resolution: 'provinces'
});

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function() {
    var selection = chart.getSelection();

    // if same city is clicked twice in a row
    // it is "unselected", and selection = []
    if(typeof selection[0] !== "undefined") {
      var value = newInfo.getValue(selection[0].row, 0);
      alert('City is: ' + value);
    }
});

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's all I'm trying to do (for now). Instead of using an alert box it's going to be sent off to look something up in the database, then route to a new page. I was using an alert box because it was an easy way to check if a value was selected.

Comment: Hmm, it seems to work perfectly in jsFiddle, however, even when I set up a new page only with this code it won't run. The only thing that appears on the page is "â€‹". I'll update my code above to reflect exactly what I have on this new page.

Comment: In my experience, JSFiddle can produce that â€‹ artifact. I posted the full HTML I used here http://pastebin.com/kURHnvMU edit: Sorry give me some time for me to see the updated code too.

Comment: Sorry for not reading carefully. I cleaned the artifacts and here's the new paste from the updated question: http://pastebin.com/2rpGXHYs It should work. It didn't occur to me the artifact would break a page, it does happen infrequently and randomly

Comment: I was hoping you would ask about how to detect the â€‹, in case you had to copy from JSFiddle again. Now I want to investigate. In my case, I use emacs editor and it complains when trying to save the file, it's not a valid unicode character. Anyway, good night!

Comment: I just figured it was some flaw on jsFiddle's part the way you described it...as in they should fix it.